# Sub-menu items showing in Firefox and IE but NOT in Chrome

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, submenu

I'm facing a weird problem with displaying the sub menu-items for a wordpress site. The sub-menu items work fine in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome. I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

The problem is when I visit the home page, the drop-down works for Chrome as well, but when I select an item from that drop-down, the hover does not work. To be specific, I can sense that the items are there but not visible. Hovering shows the sub-items links at the bottom of the browser for all the items, but it's just not visible in the menu.

The site is http://soumissionrenovation.ca/  --- the sub-items under "Votre Projet" works fine.

and try to visit http://soumissionrenovation.ca/amenagement-paysager/ --this is one of the drop-down items of "Votre Projet" and thus the drop-down does not work (you'll know once you visit the page)

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Off topic...but those negative margins are confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get rid of `overflow: hidden;` in your `#masthead`. The `.sub-menu` "overflows" the `header` container, so you need to allow `overflow: visible;` (the default).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me :-) I don't think I would check #masthead myself if you didn't mention. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Please close up this question by selecting this answer as correct. :-)